# Clock in zsh prompt

Tags: zshrc

I have seen a bunch of different zsh prompts but I was wondering how I can add a clock?

I want a simple clock, not anything too complex that self updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export RPROMPT=$'%F{cyan}%*%f'` creates a simple, blue clock on the right side of the screen.

Go here for more info [Zsh prompt](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#SEC59)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:
[liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt)

Perhaps in conjunction with
[antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen)